# Verb to refer to people yelling "wooh!"

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs

I'm looking for a verb which refers to the sound that people make when they are excited. The typical "wooh."

At first I thought it was called **wooing/wooed**. But then I checked the Free Dictionary:

> woo  (w) v. wooed, woo·ing, woos v.tr.
>   1. To seek the affection of with intent to romance.
>   2. a. To seek to achieve; try to gain. b. To tempt or invite.
>   3. To entreat, solicit, or importune. v.intr. To court a woman

And realized it was not.

What's the correct word?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You might want ***whoop***

> **whoop** /wuːp/
>   *noun*
>   **1** a loud cry of joy or excitement:
>   *a moment’s silence was followed by whoops of delight*
>
> *verb* [no object]
>   give or make a whoop:
>   *all at once they were whooping with laughter*
>
> [[ODO]](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/whoop)

Comment: Or, more generally, "cheer", in the sense of "to shout with joy, approval, or enthusiasm", but this does not describe the "wooh" sound so much. http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cheer